# User tracking through urls and avoiding manual tampering

Tags: php, tracking, identifier

I'd like to keep track of how many people follow a link sent through an email.

At the moment, I'm thinking of having a separate page which is called through the link with a get variable to indicate this was done from an email.

Obviously, this can be tampered with manually through the address bar of a navigator. What approaches could I use to limit this?

Comment: If by follow you mean click on a link you can add some parameters to the link: page.php?param1=1&param2.... or you can add a pixel to the page so anytime the email is opn you can get feedback

Comment: Checking Referer like MicronXD said is probably the best approach for this. That can obviously be spoofed/wrong as well, but most people wouldn't bother. I don't know, however, what type of link you are referring to. If it's for people that probably didn't visit the site, you could notice when they visit directly a e.g. notices page, or something like that, by checking older sessions or whatever method you want to use.

Comment: @Ibu: Yes, something like that with the id of the user. The pixel is one idea. Another is generating a single cryptic id (?crypticid=52e565sdfd54...) although that could require a bit of code.

Comment: @Filgera: The idea is to measure how effective new features are at inciting users to revisit the site. For example, an email is sent when a user posts a comment on a photo. There's a hyperlink in there which points to the profile of the poster which the receiver can click if they're curious.

Comment: You could just do something simple, like `?email=their@address.comcrypticid=52e565sdfd54` Just determine how you want to create that id, sometime simple like md5($addr."salt"); shove that in the email, and in your script just `if(md5($_GET['email']."salt") == $_GET['crypticid'])` you win.

Comment: You'd also gain the advantage of knowing which user it was so you don't double count, if you pass their email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Use a completely different URL to redirect to the real one:

`http://www.mysite.com/emailOffer` -> `http://www.mysite.com/specialpage`

emailOffer would do the logging, and then send a `Location` HTTP header pointing to the real page (specialpage)

`http://www.mysite.com/emailOffer` would look like this:

```
/* SOME LOGGING CODE GOES HERE - PROBABLY MYSQL STUFFS */
header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/specialpage");
```

2)Add a GET parameter like: `http://www.mysite.com/specialpage?email`
then in php, you can do: `if(array_key_exists('email',$_GET)) addToCounter();`

3)You could log the HTTP Referer header for everyone who hits the page and run a query for referers containing "mail" (e.g., mail.google.com, hotmail.com)

To help prevent tampering, you could make the parameter seem worth while:
`http://www.mysite.com/specialpage?secretOffer`

Good luck! :)

PS - sorry for the terrible formatting of my answer...

Answer (score 1):

In most cases people probably just use the GET method, in all cases though, it can be tampered with, pretty much every element can be changed if a person really wants to, but as far as telling where someone is going from you're pretty much stuck with GET or checking the referrer, which can be highly suspect, and you'd have to check all sorts of things.

If you aren't concerned with the actual link they're following in the email, you could create a secondary page, that hits your counter, outputs nothing, and just redirects them like

```
<?php
... do counter stuff ....
header('Location: http://actual.address.com/');
?>
```

Their navigation bar will change to the new address, and they'll barely even notice the original.